# Make class to encapsulate isLong/isDouble Function

Tags: c#

i'm trying to make a class that contains 4 functions: isLong, isDouble, stringToLong, and stringToDouble. I am trying to do this without using a TryParse function. Ideally this class would receive a string and return the appropriate type (bool, bool, long, and double) in respective order.

For instance if i enter the number 100000 it returns True (bool) for isLong.

Below is an example of how i did isLong but i am having difficulty trying to do the same for isDouble for receiving decimals and for both stringToLong/stringToDouble.

```
public static bool isLong(string s)
    {
        bool ret = true;
        int i;
        s = s.Trim();
        if (s[0] == '-')
        {
            i = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
        }
        for (; (i < s.Length); i = i + 1)
        {
            ret = ret && ((s[i] >= '0') && (s[i] <= '9'));
        }
        return (ret);
    }
```

Comment: Is there something specific about your implementation that precludes the use of `TryParse()`?

Comment: It isn't something that I have used up to this point in programming, i'm in a collegiate programming course. I've researched and been successful in using TryParse() by doing the following functions but they're not functions i have used in the class thus far.

Comment: public static bool isLong(string numString)
    {
    long number1 = 0;
    bool canConvert = long.TryParse(numString, out number1);
    return canConvert;
    }

    public static bool isDouble(string numString)
    {
    double number1 = 0;
    bool canConvert = double.TryParse(numString, out number1);
    return canConvert;
    }

Comment: FYI: The method `isLong` in your question does not reliably tell whether a string represents a long or not (it can give false positives). A `long` (and any other primitive numeric data type in C#/.NET, for that matter) has a given value range. I see your `isLong` method checking whether a string represents some number, but i don't see `isLong` checking for whether that number represented by the string falls within the value range of `long`. (Try for example this string with your isLong method: `"12345678901234567890"`. Then try parsing the same string using long.TryParse...)

Comment: @Sean Bruce that's really complicated. The `TryParse()` can be simplified to something like this: `long l; return long.TryParse(numString, out l);`. In more recent versions of C#, you can move the initialization of the `out` variable to inside the call like so: `return long.TryParse(numString, out long l);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use MinValue and MaxValue properties for check numeric types, for instance you could define a method like this:

```
public bool IsLong(decimal value)
{
   return value >= long.MinValue && value <= long.MaxValue && value == (long)value;
}
```